# disable touchpad through xinput

Tags: linux, xinput

I am trying to disable touchpad through xinput. But I cannot find the id for my touchpad...
Here is xinput list:

```
Virtual core pointer                          id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ DLL07A9:01 044E:120B                      id=14   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ GTech MI wireless mouse Mouse             id=11   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ GTech MI wireless mouse Consumer Control  id=13   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ DualPoint Stick                           id=15   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                         id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Sleep Button                              id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Integrated_Webcam_HD: Integrate           id=10   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Intel HID events                          id=16   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Intel HID 5 button array                  id=17   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Dell WMI hotkeys                          id=18   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard              id=19   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ GTech MI wireless mouse System Control    id=12   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ GTech MI wireless mouse Consumer Control  id=20   [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

I am using dell precision 3520 and running arch linux(if that is related). Can someone tell me what id corresponds to my touchpad and how you know?

Answer (score 2):

It should be the `DLL07A9:01 044E:120B` device. See [Aquantia Corp. DLL07A9:01 044E:120B Touchpad](https://certification.ubuntu.com/catalog/component/input/4932/input%3ADLL07A9%3A01044E%3A120B/).

Either do:

```
xinput disable DLL07A9:01 044E:120B
xinput enable DLL07A9:01 044E:120B
```

Or use the XID (I suspect, this is more fragile because it could change):

```
xinput disable 14
xinput enable 14
```

Comment: `xinput set-prop 14 "Device Enabled" 0` would also work.